# Regrid 2D data onto larger 2D grid at given coordinates in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have a square 2D array `data` that I would like to add to a larger 2D array `frame` at some given set of non-integer coordinates `coords`. The idea is that `data` will be interpolated onto `frame` with it's center at the new coordinates.

Some toy data:

```
# A gaussian to add to the frame
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10), np.linspace(-1,1,10))
data = 50*np.exp(-np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)**2)

# The frame to add the gaussian to
frame = np.random.normal(size=(100,50))

# The desired (x,y) location of the gaussian center on the new frame
coords = 23.4, 22.6
```

Here's the idea. I want to add this:

[image: gaussian]

to this:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

If the coordinates were integers (indexes), of course I could simply add them like this:

```
frame[23:33,22:32] += data
```

But I want to be able to specify non-integer coordinates so that `data` is regridded and added to `frame`.

I've looked into `PIL.Image` methods but my use case is just for 2D data, not images. Is there a way to do this with just `scipy`? Can this be done with `interp2d` or a similar function? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the coordinates of `frame`? So you just want to replace a part of `frame` with `data`?

Comment: @anishtain4 Oh, sorry. The coordinates of `frame` are just the indexes. And not replace. I want to add it.

Comment: So do you want to resize the data or not? If the indices overlap exactly with those of frame, then my answer is the most simple way, because `shift` will do it. If not, then the other answer is the most generic and best.

Comment: The "coordinates" of pixels in the `data` image (`x` and `y`) are spaced by 0.222(2) units ("pixel scale")  - see `np.linspace(-1,1,10)` so that if mapped to the output `frame` grid (assuming spacing of 1 pixel) would result in the `data` image shrink to just 2 pixels in size when placed into the output `frame` image. However, your example image does not show this scaling transformation. So, my question is: Is `linspace` used to generate a "true" coordinate grid or is it used just create a grid for the Gaussian and the pixel grid of `data` is the "true" coordinate system for `data` pixels?

Comment: Did you had a chance to try my answer? I believe it also should give you the same results in a much simpler manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [`scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html). In the code below, `x_0` and `y_0` are the coordinates of a feature from data (i.e., the position of the center of the Gaussian in your example) that need to be mapped to the coordinates given by `coords`. There are a couple of advantages to this approach:

1. If you need to "place" the same object into multiple locations in the output `frame`, the spline needs to be computed only once (but evaluated multiple times).
2. In case you actually need to compute integrated flux of the model over a pixel, you can use the [`integral` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.integral.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.integral) of `scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline`.

Resample using spline interpolation:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
x = np.arange(data.shape[1], dtype=np.float)
y = np.arange(data.shape[0], dtype=np.float)
kx = 3; ky = 3; # spline degree
spline = RectBivariateSpline(
    x, y, data.T, kx=kx, ky=ky, s=0
)

# Define coordinates of a feature in the data array.
# This can be the center of the Gaussian:
x_0 = (data.shape[1] - 1.0) / 2.0
y_0 = (data.shape[0] - 1.0) / 2.0

# create output grid, shifted as necessary:
yg, xg = np.indices(frame.shape, dtype=np.float64)
xg += x_0 - coords[0] # see below how to account for pixel scale change
yg += y_0 - coords[1] # see below how to account for pixel scale change

# resample and fill extrapolated points with 0:
resampled_data = spline.ev(xg, yg)
extrapol = (((xg < -0.5) | (xg >= data.shape[1] - 0.5)) |
            ((yg < -0.5) | (yg >= data.shape[0] - 0.5)))
resampled_data[extrapol] = 0
```

Now plot the `frame` and resampled `data`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14));
plt.imshow(frame+resampled_data, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
          origin='upper', interpolation='none', aspect='equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you also want to allow for scale changes, then replace code for computing `xg` and `yg` above with:

```
coords = 20, 80 # change coords to easily identifiable (in plot) values
zoom_x = 2 # example scale change along X axis
zoom_y = 3 # example scale change along Y axis
yg, xg = np.indices(frame.shape, dtype=np.float64)
xg = (xg - coords[0]) / zoom_x + x_0
yg = (yg - coords[1]) / zoom_y + y_0
```

[image]

Most likely this is what you actually want based on your example. Specifically, the coordinates of pixels in `data` are "spaced" by 0.222(2) distance units. Therefore it actually seems that for your particular example (whether accidental or intentional), you have a zoom factor of 0.222(2). In that case your `data` image would shrink to almost 2 pixels in the output frame.

---

#### Comparison to `@Chiel` answer

In the image below, I compare the results from my method (left), `@Chiel`'s method (center) and difference (right panel):

[image]

Fundamentally, the two methods are quite similar and possibly even use the same algorithm (I did not look at the code for `shift` but based on the description - it also uses splines). From comparison image it is visible that the biggest differences are at the edges and, for unknown to me reasons, `shift` seems to truncate the shifted image slightly too soon.

I think the biggest difference is that my method allows for pixel scale changes and it also allows re-use of the same interpolator to place the original image at different locations in the output frame. `@Chiel`'s method is somewhat simpler but (what I did not like about it is that) it requires creation of a larger array (`data_large`) into which the original image is placed in the corner.

Comment: @Chiel Are you sure? I did not test your answer, but nothing bad jumped at me right away. Could you, please restore it, at least temporary, so that I can test it?

Comment: I restored my answer. I have added the conditions under which it works, and when your solution is desired. Yours is more generic, but if shift suffices it is preferred.

Comment: Great that you compared the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Scipy's [`shift`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift.html) function from `scipy.ndimage.interpolation` is what you are looking for, as long as the grid spacings between `data` and `frame` overlap. If not, look to the other answer. The `shift` function can take floating point numbers as input and will do a spline interpolation. First, I put the data into an array as large as frame, then shift it, and then add it. Make sure to reverse the coordinate list, as `x` is the rightmost dimension in `numpy` arrays. One of the nice features of shift is that it sets to zero those values that go out of bounds.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

# A gaussian to add to the frame.
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10), np.linspace(-1,1,10))
data = 50*np.exp(-np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)**2)

# The frame to add the gaussian to
frame = np.random.normal(size=(100,50))
x_frame = np.arange(50)
y_frame = np.arange(100)

# The desired (x,y) location of the gaussian center on the new frame.
coords = np.array([23.4, 22.6])

# First, create a frame as large as the frame.
data_large = np.zeros(frame.shape)
data_large[:data.shape[0], :data.shape[1]] = data[:,:]

# Subtract half the distance as the bottom left is at 0,0 instead of the center.
# The shift of 4.5 is because data is 10 points wide.
# Reverse the coords array as x is the last coordinate.
coords_shift = -4.5
data_large = shift(data_large, coords[::-1] + coords_shift)

frame += data_large

# Plot the result and add lines to indicate to coordinates
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(x_frame, y_frame, frame, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.axhline(coords[1], color='w')
plt.axvline(coords[0], color='w')
plt.colorbar()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

The script gives you the following figure, which has the desired coordinates indicated with white dotted lines.

[image: Interpolated result]

Comment: See my latest edit to my answer. I did not find anything wrong with your answer and I think you should keep it: it is slightly simple than mine (but not much, IMO). It is a valid answer, IMO and you should keep it.

Comment: Also, I think your `coords_shift=-5` should be -4.5 because center of the Gaussian is at 4.5 pixels. This is not a major thing and, actually, it depends on which convention is adopted: origin in the corner or at the center of the pixel. (I had to set `coords_shift` to -4.5 to compare to my output.)

Comment: Great that you have restored your answer! It would be a shame not to have more options.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have gone into detail, but here's my lazy solution:

```
xc,yc = 23.4, 22.6
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10)-xc%1, np.linspace(-1,1,10)-yc%1)
data = 50*np.exp(-np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)**2)
frame = np.random.normal(size=(100,50))
frame[23:33,22:32] += data
```

And it's the way you liked it. As you mentioned, the coordinates of both are the same, so the origin of `data` is somewhere between the indices. Now just simply shift it by the amount you want it to be off a grid point (remainder to one) in the second line and you're good to go (you might need to flip the sign, but I think this is correct).